# Rails Minitest Stub Class method called inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

How can I stub a method that is called inside a controller when simulating a request?

What I've tryied:

```
require 'test_helper'
class ConfirmationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test 'dummy test' do
    User.stub(:some_method, 'string') do
      p User.some_method
      get(:index)
    end
  end
end

class ConfirmationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    p User.some_method
  end
end
```

When I print `User.some_method` inside the stub it works, but when I use the method inside my controller action it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance

e.g. (from their docs)

```
String.stub_any_instance(:length, 42) do
  assert_equal "hello".length, 42
end
```